# RX Swift - Parallel Execution of APIs

Tags: ios, swift, observable, observer-pattern, rx-swift

I want to use RX  in a way that it will download data from multiple APIs and combine all of them. All of them would execute in parallel and then combine data from the response of all of them. I am executing them in nested calls here & i would like convert the code.

```
public func searchListings(searchState: SearchState,
                             renderState: SearchRenderState) -  Observable<PropertyNetworkResponse  {
        return Observable.create({ (observer) -  Disposable in

      _ = self.getXData(searchState: searchState, renderState: renderState).subscribe(onNext: { (xData) in

        _ = self.getYData(searchState: searchState, renderState: renderState).subscribe(onNext: { (yData) in

          _ = self.getZData(searchState: searchState, renderState: renderState).subscribe(onNext: { (zData) in

          let results = xData + yData + zData


          observer.onNext(resultNetworkResponse)
          observer.onCompleted()

          }, onError: { (error) in

            observer.onError(error)

          }, onCompleted: nil, onDisposed: nil)
        }, onError: { (error) in

          observer.onError(error)

        }, onCompleted: nil, onDisposed: nil)

      }, onError: { error in

        observer.onError(error)

      }, onCompleted: nil, onDisposed: nil)

      return Disposables.create()   
    }) 
  }
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a platform where others do your work for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recently I faced a similar problem and I was able to make parallel network calls using `zip`. Try the following code:

```
public func searchListings(searchState: SearchState,
                         renderState: SearchRenderState) -  Observable<PropertyNetworkResponse  {

    let observableX = self.getXData(searchState: searchState, renderState: renderState)
    let observableY = self.getYData(searchState: searchState, renderState: renderState)
    let observableZ = self.getZData(searchState: searchState, renderState: renderState)   

    return Observable.create({ (observer) -> Disposable in

        _ = Observable.zip(observableX, observableY, observableZ) { ($0, $1, $2) }
        .subscribe(onNext: { xData, yData, zData in
            let result = xData + yData + zData

            observer.onNext(resultNetworkResponse)
            observer.onCompleted()
        })
        return Disposables.create()   
    }) 
}
```

Please find info about how `zip` works in this [link](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html)